# Get image from URL and change to plainfile and send to Stripe as plainfile

Tags: php, wordpress, stripe-payments

I am successfully creating custom accounts and persons through the Stripe API. I am at the verification step where I need to send an identity document to Stripe for verification. However, I'm receiving the following error when attempting to send the image:

> Only plainfile resource streams are supported

Here's the code:

```
$filePath = 'http://localhost:81/battlestardigital/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/Fanboy-forever-2.jpg';
$filePurpose = 'identity_document';
$stripeAccountID = 'acct_myaccountkey';

$fp = fopen($filePath, 'r');

$uploadResponse = \Stripe\File::create(
    [                
        'purpose' => $filePurpose,
        'file' => $fp
    ],
    ['stripe_account' => $stripeAccountID]
);
```

var_dumping the file tells me the stream_type is "tcp_socket/ssl," so that makes sense. Where I'm stuck is how to take this and send a "plainfile" to Stripe.

I've been going down the path of using `imagejpeg` to create a temporary image, but I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way to accomplish the goal.

Am I missing something obvious?

**EDIT:** So it turns out all I had to do was drop the http and initial and site info from the path. In this case, that meant dropping "http://localhost:81/battlestardigital" from the path using `strstr`. Now I'm receiving an invalid hash error. Will track down a solution for this, then post everything as an answer.

**EDIT 2:** And invalid hash due to typo. DOH! Posting full solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case I was testing from my local host before pushing out to production. I imagine the same thing would have applied in Prod, though I didn't push the buggy code so I can't say for sure.

At any rate, because my file path included "http," PHP naturally set the stream_type to "tcp_socket/ssl." By removing that portion of the file path, I was able to open the file as a plainfile and send to Stripe. Here's the final code from my test page:

```
$imgUrl = 'http://localhost:81/battlestardigital/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/Fanboy-forever-2.jpg';
$filePath = get_home_path() . strstr($imgUrl, '/wp-content');
$filePurpose = 'identity_document';
$stripeAccountID = 'acct_myaccountkey';

$fp = fopen($filePath, 'r');

$uploadResponse = \Stripe\File::create(
    [                
        'purpose' => $filePurpose,
        'file' => $fp
    ],
    ['stripe_account' => $stripeAccountID]
);

fclose($fp);
```

I hope this helps!